# Sharepoint online list Create Folder and insert item in it

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, newforms

I am trying to create folder into share point list and add items into newly created folder.

Currently i am open newform.aspx page with folder path which was not already exists as below:-
https://sharepointonline.com/sites/SiteName/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1&RootFolder=/sites/SiteName/Lists/ListName/Folder1/Folder2

When user click on save button with items details i am creating Folder1 and Folder2 using code into presave. Folders are created successfully but item is not inserted into it, it throws error that folder path not exists.

If i refresh page and try to add item, it will easily inserted into folder.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

JSOM/Rest api are asynchronous，you should try to delay the add item function and return when previous function complete.

Try to use jQuery `Deferred` for this case.

You may check [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232390/create-folder-in-recently-created-folder/232460#232460) for a sample demo.